# Getting nullpointer exception when adding tabs?

Tags: android, tabs

Hi when i am trying to add tabs i am getting nullpointer exception.I am creating one activity MyLanguageActivity this extends Activity and i am creating one more activity MyTabActivity this extends TabActivity.Inside of MyLangugeActivity i am selecting language and i am tapping on done button i am adding tabs one more time like this :

```
public void setTabs(){
Intent intent, intent1, intent2, intent3;
    TabHost tabHost = MyTabActivity.tabHost;
    System.out.println(tabHost);
    TextView tv;
    intent = new Intent(
            "com.activitygroups.RequestTabActivtyGroup");
    intent1 = new Intent(
            "com.activitygroups.OffersTabActivityGroup");

    intent.putExtra("content", "requests");
    intent1.putExtra("content", "offers");


    System.out.println("request string : "
            + getResources().getString(R.string.requests));
    System.out.println("drowable id : "
            + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.request_tab_selector));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("request_tab")
            .setIndicator(
                    LanguageUtils.getLanguage(MyLanguageActivity.this,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.requests)),
                    getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.request_tab_selector))
            .setContent(
                    new Intent(intent)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

}
```

inside og done button onclick i am calling this method.When i tap on done i am getting nullpointer exception.. My logcat here :

```
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at         android.widget.TabWidget.setCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:339)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:363)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.melhoroferta.LanguageSettingActivity.setUpTabs(MyLanguageActivity.java:204)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at com.melhoroferta.LanguageSettingActivity.onClick(MyLanguageActivity.java:142)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
         02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
          02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
   02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
        02-10 12:32:37.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry guys i am forgot to remove those intent 2 and intent 3 actually this intents are i am not using..

Comment: Hello Rajesh, nullpointerexception bcaz of not created objects of intent2,intent3.

Comment: this must be as answer @AmolSawant96Kuli

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli post it as answer..

Comment: Rajesh as @AmolSawant96Kuli said your Intents are not init..that too you are not using it anywhere why you need it..

Comment: please check my edit.i am not using this intent 2 and intent 3.sorry i forgot to remove this intents.I am getting exceptions in tabhost.addTab(...) in this line..

Comment: so your question was solved? If so you could accept on of the answers :)

Answer (score 4):

```
 intent = new Intent(
            "com.activitygroups.RequestTabActivtyGroup");
 intent1 = new Intent(
            "com.activitygroups.OffersTabActivityGroup");
```

Add `Intents`,

```
 intent2 = new Intent(
            "profile activity");
 intent3 = new Intent(
            "setting activity");
```

Comment: please check my edit.i am not using this intent 2 and intent 3.sorry i forgot to remove this intents.I am getting exceptions in tabhost.addTab(...) in this line..

Comment: might be problem with this. setContent(new Intent(intent)    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))); try to replace with .setContent(intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your `intent2` and `intent3`.Because you use `.putExtra` to 2 not initialized Intents

Just add:

```
intent2 = new Intent(); //put in the brackets what you want or need
intent3 = new Intent();
```

Comment: please check my edit.i am not using this intent 2 and intent 3.sorry i forgot to remove this intents.I am getting exceptions in tabhost.addTab(...) in this line..